# Why are the indexes off when accessing the contents of tr tags inside a tbody tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

There are 8 individual tr tags inside of a Tbody, with their own respective contents. I count 8 in the source from the page, and when I run len(inTbody) it tells me 8, so I know there are 8 tr tags. However, when I do inTbody[0], it returns blank. inTbody[1] gives me the contents of only the first tr tag. When I do inTbody[7] it lists the contents of the 4th tr tag, which should really be the 3rd tr tag due to computer indexes, but alongside listing the contents of the 4th tr tag, it lists the contents of the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th! It seems so arbitrary and randomized, Ive spent over an hour trying to figure out the ordering of the indexes amongst the tags and contents and I'm really lost.

```
import csv
import bs4
import urllib
from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#For sites that can't be opened due to Urllib blocker, use a 
#Mozilla User agent to get access
pageRequest = Request('https://coronavirusbellcurve.com/', headers 
= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
htmlPage = urlopen(pageRequest).read()
page_soup = soup(htmlPage, 'html.parser')
#overarchDiv = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class": "main"})
specificDiv = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "table-responsive- 
xl"})

inTbody = specificDiv.table.tbody.contents
print(len(inTbody))
print(inTbody[7])
```

Comment: If you check the contents of the list, it is correct because it looks like the following. `[[],[tf1],[],[tr2],[],[tr3],[tr4tr5tr6tr7tr8]]`

Comment: Why is it like that? Why doesn't it use ordinary ordering with index 0 to tr1, 1 to tr2, etc. Like tr45678 all being bunched up into 7 just seems so arbitrary to me @r-beginners